# How can I estimate the density of fog?

Tags: drag, density

I'm working on investigating the effect fog has on drag. I have assumed an air density of $1.225 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$ for dry air, but I don't know what value for density I could assume that would be typical of fog.

I can't even reason out whether or not fog is more dense or less dense than dry air: I know that air density is lower at higher humidity since water vapor is less dense than air, but it seems to me that fog should have a higher density than air, since you can observe fog being more dense closer to the ground, and collecting in valleys.

What air density is typical of fog?

Comment: In this http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-air-d_680.html dry air is shown to be denser than humid. and this says how density of air is measured http://www.npl.co.uk/upload/pdf/buoycornote.pdf

Comment: http://www.elmhurst.edu/~chm/vchembook/123Adensitygas.html confirms that fog is denser than air (since, as you note, it sinks and condenses), but doesn't provide any actual numbers. Also possibly helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_water_content http://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2011/09/12/how-much-condensed-liquid-water-is-in-a-cubic-mile-of-fog/

Comment: by statistics, if one googles "is humid air denser than dry air" a lot of  links come up " why dry air is heavier than humid air" . The reason is that H2O molecule  is lighter than O2 and Nitrogen molecules that they displace at that temperature and pressure, thus density falls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [instrument](http://www.aei.tuke.sk/papers/2012/2/10_Ovsen%C3%ADk.pdf) that measures fog density and has an experimental plot, figure 9  .

Once you have the relative humidity at the fog appearance at a temperature and pressure , one can use known equations to get the density. [This link](http://www.brisbanehotairballooning.com.au/faqs/education/116-calculate-air-density.html) gives a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has ever seen fog pour over a mountain range can tell you that it is significantly more dense than either moist or dry air.   It does, after all, settle to the bottom of valleys....

See https://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/news/video-1031660/Incredible-wave-fog-rolls-Canadian-mountain-range.html for a nice example.

I have no clue where to get a quantitative answer, but qualitatively it seem denser.

I came here looking for for an explanation for a significant loss of range in my EV when driving through dense fog.  It is again, an empirical qualitative result, but it does seem like I needed to charge a lot more than when I do this same reasonably routine drive in dry air.